# Core Data creating new objects Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, store

New to iOS development..

Basically what i'm trying to do is hard code data into my app using core data. Two different types will be stored, both strings: quotes and authors (There will be around 20 of each in the app).  I have a button on my Storyboard as an IBaction that when clicked will populate a label with a new quote and author.  My struggle right now is 1) finding out how to create this data and 2) how to fetch this data.

Every resource i'm finding online goes through tutorials on how to store data that a user typed in and then fetch it from a button. I'm trying to figure out how to store data without user input and then fetch it.  Any help is appreciated. Sorry for asking what I am sure is a pretty simple question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, though this would seem like a simple task, to my knowledge there is know "built-in" way to prepopulate CoreData.  You can build up a core database and then copy it into an app, or possibly use a third party solution, though.  Searching for "prepopulate coredata" here and on google should give you a start.

Here's a couple threads that might help:

[Any way to pre populate core data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230354/any-way-to-pre-populate-core-data)

[iOS CoreData - prepopulate db with existing indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388736/ios-coredata-prepopulate-db-with-existing-indexes)

Comment: Also if you use some existing resource : http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated